# Would debugging help with custom syntax highlighting .vim files be on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I wrote a custom syntax highlighting `.vim` file that doesn't work. Would posting it and explaining what it's supposed to do be on topic?

What if I was able to write an MCVE?

In either case, would the question be more on topic here, or on SO?

Comment: Explain what "MCVE" means?

Comment: @200_success [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 8):

Yes, I believe that such questions should be on-topic, subject to a quality threshold.  There needs to be a specific question of what text should and shouldn't be matched, a specific broken example, and enough code to troubleshoot the problem.

Furthermore, the relevant code needs to be embedded in the question itself, not just a link to a third-party site.

Comment: I would add: remember what M stands for in MCVE: **minimal**. Remove anything unnecessary from your file before posting. (Very likely you'll debug the problem this way, but that's another thing.)